# Apache multiport single ip Fedora

Tags: apache

So I want to run multiport in 1 ip addr in Fedora. That what I set up for the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

[image]

And this is the conf html in these /var/www/

[image]

when I go to nguyen.com, it corrects, but I when I go to nguyen.com:8080, the apache server serve the html port 80 ( not port 8080)

How can I fix it. thanks

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about posting text as text, not a pictures.

Comment: Also please read the description of the tags you selected. [tag:apache] says: Note that server configuration questions are usually a better fit on https://serverfault.com